#  How to edit showInPanes property in XtraCharts

Tags: devexpress, pane

I am adding series and panes to a Developer's Express Chart Control in code on a windows form application.  I would like to only show the x-axis labels for the first pane.  The showInPanes property is telling me it is read only.  How do I set this propert in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim XyDiagram1 As XYDiagram = CType(chart.Diagram, XYDiagram)

Dim XyDiagramPane1 As XYDiagramPane = New XYDiagramPane
XyDiagramPane1.Name = "Pane 1"
XyDiagram1.Panes.Add(XyDiagramPane1)

XyDiagram1.AxisX.SetVisibilityInPanes(False, XyDiagramPane1)
```